# How do you do Integration Tests in ASP.NET Boilerplate if your application requires authentication from a third party single sign on authorizer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, integration-testing, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate with ASP.NET MVC, not Core.  How do I test an MVC Controller where my application requires authentication first from a Single Sign On third party?

I can't find anything, so I have no code other than to reproduce basic Unit Tests (which aren't integration tests), but it's only copy and paste with nothing to do with this question.  I don't use any async or spa, etc.  Regular old ASP.NET MVC 4.6.